# ggplot2 heatmap with a heatmap vector downside and a values vector aside

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Dear experts I would like to draw a heatmap from the (n-1)(m-1) values table below. With a heatmap vector below the principal heatmap representing the "MAX" row and a values vector representing the
"MEAN" column at left side the principal heatmap.

[image]

```r
  Adrenal gland Bladder urothelium  Breast  Cervical tissue Colorectal tissue   Esophagus   Kidney  Lung    Pancreas    Prostate    Stomach Thyroid Uterus  MEAN
rm500   1   1   0.99562363238512    0.411764705882353   0.381136950904393   0.549485352335709   1   0.99822695035461    1   0.638297872340426   0.224719101123595   0.996825396825397   0.50354609929078    0.746125081649414
rm500dropout    1   1   0.99781181619256    0.647058823529412   0.723735408560311   0.294754371357202   1   1   1   0.424242424242424   0.166112956810631   0.98159509202454    0.492753623188406   0.748312655069653
rf  1   0.80952380952381    0.945414847161572   0.105263157894737   0.987163029525032   0.98961937716263    1   0.998269896193772   1   0.991803278688525   0.972144846796657   0.996927803379416   0.97887323943662    0.905769483520213
knn 1   0.857142857142857   0.925925925925926   0.315789473684211   0.985879332477535   0.987543252595156   1   0.998269896193772   1   0.97119341563786    0.974930362116992   0.996927803379416   0.971830985915493   0.921956408082248
MAX 1   1   0.99781181619256    0.647058823529412   0.987163029525032   0.98961937716263    1   1   1   0.991803278688525   0.974930362116992   0.996927803379416   0.97887323943662    0.966475979233168
```

This is the best try I did. Below the code you find the obtained plot.

```r
#-Packages
if(!require('ggheatmapper')) {
    install.packages('ggheatmapper')
    library('ggheatmapper')
}

if(!require('tidyverse')) {
    install.packages('tidyverse')
    library('tidyverse')
}

#-Input
sensi=read.table("./sensitivity_all.tsv", sep='\t', header=TRUE, 
                 row.names=1)
#-Main
method=rownames(sensi)
tb1 <- cbind(method, sensi)

#-- Separating metadata from data
row_meta <- tb1 %>%
    filter(method != "MAX") %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(method, MEAN)

#-- Pivot data table
tb_pivot <- tb1 %>%
    select(-MEAN) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = colnames(tb1)[-c(1, length(colnames(tb1)))], 
                 names_to = "cancer_type") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = method, values_from = value)

png("sensitivity.png", width=1000, height=700)

#-- Main heatmap
hm <- ggheatmap(tb_pivot,
          colv = "cancer_type",
           rowv = method[-length(row.names(tb1))],
          cluster_rows = FALSE,
          colors_title = "Sensitivity",
          hm_color_limits = c(0,1),
          hm_colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, "Blues"),
          clustering_method = "ward.D2",
          fontsize = 25,
          show_dend_row = FALSE,
          show_colnames = FALSE)

#-- Add tracks
max_track <- tb_pivot %>%
    mutate(cancer_type = factor(cancer_type, levels = get_colLevels(hm)),
           var = "MAX") %>%
    ggplot(aes(cancer_type, var, fill = MAX)) +
    geom_tile() +
    labs(x = " ") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, "Blues"),
                         limits = c(0, 1)) +
    guides(fill = "none") +
    theme_sparse3() + theme_gray(base_size = 20) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, 
                                     size=15,  face = "bold" ),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
          legend.text=element_text(size=15,  face = "bold"))

#-- Mean text
method_mean <- row_meta %>%
    mutate(method = factor(method, levels = c("MAX", get_rowLevels(hm))),
           var = "MEAN") %>%
    ggplot(aes(var, method, label = sprintf("%.3f", MEAN))) + 
           #format(mean, nsmall=3))) +
    geom_text(size=8) +
    scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"), 
          legend.title=element_text(size=35, face = "bold"),  
    legend.text=element_text(size=35, ,face = "bold"), 
               text = element_text(size = 35) )

hm %>%
    align_to_hm(max_track, newplt_size_prop = 0.1) %>%
    align_to_hm(method_mean, newplt_size_prop = 0.1, pos = "right",
                legend_action = "collect")


dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Specifically what step are you stuck in, and what is the minimal code to get stuck in this step?

Comment: @teunbrand I am stuck in getting the values vector down to the level of the heatmap vector, in order to display the mean of the max row. I want also the rows to be ordered downward with respect to increasing mean values. I want the columns ordered alphabetically with respect to the class names. And I want to get rid of the lines scheme on the top of the principal heatmap. For the minimal code I think what I gave is maximally reduced functional code.